# How to limit the Future dates on GWT datepicker

Tags: gwt, datepicker

I am working on an application which has a DOB selection. So, this date cannot be in future.

I will put a check using a ValueChangeHandler because it is possible the user manually types a future date, but is there a way to disable all future dates in the DatePicker, so that user cannot select a future date ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a link to GWT JavaDoc for DatePicker:

[Class DatePicker](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/datepicker/client/DatePicker.html)

It lists all methods available for DatePicker. You may try `.setTransientEnabledOnDates()`.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, this method takes a list of dates which can be enabled/disabled, but future is infinite. Maybe I could disable next 20 years and hope the user will not look anything over that. I was hoping for something more robust.

Comment: This method is used to disable *visible* dates. You cannot see more than 42 dates in a DatePicker at any given time.